# T-SQL trim not working - let spaces on the result

Tags: t-sql, trim

I have a trim function that apply ltrim and rtrim

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))
END
GO
```

I do the following query:

```
SELECT distinct dbo.trim([subject]) as subject
FROM [DISTR]
```

The result has rows like:

```
"A"
"A  "
"B"
...
```

I thought that thoose chars maybe weren't spaces but when I got the ascii code, it returns 32 which is the code for space.

My only guess is that I had to change the collaction of the database to: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI

Can that be the problem? Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Now I've edited, do you have " in the actual results? or was that formatting?

Comment: I presume the quotation marks are to show what the individual strings look like and are not actually part of the string?

Comment: I'd recommend including a binary representation of the string giving you problems.  Something like `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST([subject] AS VARBINARY))` in the select should do it.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Please supply DDL and insert statements for table [DISTR].

Comment: Please specify the version of sql server

Comment: @UnZynpernet, it is considered polite to accept answers to your questions. To a large extent, you have neglected to do so. You may want to go back and accept answers to your previous questions. This may motivate further help from other StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your field contains more than spaces. Remember than " " could be a space, tab, and [many other "blank" chars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). It's possible to match it using [ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) or building a CLR implementation of trim that uses regular expressions